# Infinispan: storing large objects > RAM size?

Tags: java, infinispan

Is it possible to use Infinispan for objects that are larger than the VM's total avilable RAM by supplying it with a store?

Update

I found this link which seems to indicate streaming support starting with infinispan 9: http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#hot_rod_protocol_2_6

Answer (score 0):

Infinispan is not designed for storing single huge object (or object graph), the expected data model are key-value pairs where each pair has kilobytes, or few MBs at most. The total number of such pairs is not limited, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Jira for this (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-78) but it hasn't received attention in a long long time.